# pymongo/mongodb: query if an element in an array of mongodb object

Tags: python, mongodb

If I would like to query if a field in an array I can do this

```
students.find({'name':{$in:['Mark','Jerry']}})
```

But what if I would like to find a string is in a array of an mongodb object like

```
{
  "name":"Jerry",
  "classes":["math","english","nature"]
}
```

How do I query if a class name "science" in classes array of this mongodb object?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just:

```
db.students.find({'classes': 'science'})
```